# You should not use <Link> outside a <Router> error while creating tutorial app with react-admin

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I'm using [this](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Tutorial.html) tutorial to create admin panel with react-admin library.
According to that, I put this code

```
import React from 'react';
import { Admin, Resource, ListGuesser } from 'react-admin';
import jsonServerProvider from 'ra-data-json-server';

const dataProvider = jsonServerProvider('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com');
const App = () => (
    <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider}>
        <Resource name="users" list={ListGuesser} />
    </Admin>
);

export default App;
```

into my App.js file, but I'm stuck with this error:

```
You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>
```

I've tried to clone repository and run finished tutorial example, but had the same error. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Error stacktrace: https://pastebin.com/mUu497Ev

index.js file generated with create-react-app:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Answer (score 1):

can you please provide your index.js file?
it seems there is conflict in the App name for the App.js file or else you have used react router somewhere and forgot to include   around the  App.

Comment: you should import the router package like this :
in index.js:
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
   
      <App />
   
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")....

Comment: Nope. Still the same error. My new index.js: https://pastebin.com/vDqhcLkv

Comment: try import {App}  from './App' as es6 differs

Answer (score 1):

**Routing in React:
https://codesandbox.io/s/q749j486kw**

**Pages**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

class Page1 extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Link to="/">HOME</Link>
        <Link to="/Page2">PAGE2</Link>
        <Link to="/Page3">PAGE3</Link>
        <Text>
          <h1>Page1</h1>
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Page1;
```

**Main Page:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Page1 from "./Page1.jsx";
import Page2 from "./Page2.jsx";
import Page3 from "./Page3.jsx";
import Home from "./Home.jsx";

export default class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <View>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/Page1" component={Page1} />
          <Route path="/Page2" component={Page2} />
          <Route path="/Page3" component={Page3} />
        </View>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ yarn remove react-router-dom
$ yarn add react-router-dom
```

I had a similar problem, as it turned out, because different versions of react-router and react-router-dom were installed. Try deleting with yarn, then, if they remain, delete them from the node_modules folder. And then install react-router-dom using yarn